# Why does the rc.status file set the LC_ALL locale

Tags: shell, daemontools

I am currently creating a daemon service and in order to leverage existing service functionality, the startup script sources from /etc/status.

This causes a problem with our service because within the first line, the locale is set to POSIX:

```
# Do _not_ be fooled by non POSIX locale
LC_ALL=POSIX
export LC_ALL
```

The problem is that the services which gets started from the script inherit this locale setting.
The simple fix around this would be to unset the locale prior to starting the child process. However, I do not know the implications of this. What are the consequences of re-setting the LC_ALL variable after sourcing from rc.status?

Answer (score 3):

Many system daemons behave oddly if they are invoked with a non-POSIX locale; in particular, they often don't handle UTF-8 collation, which ignores case and punctuation.  Non-POSIX time formats can also result in logfiles that can't be parsed by standard tools, which generally expect a fixed time format.  More rarely, `LC_CTYPE` can cause problems.

In general, if you need the system-wide locale setting in a daemon, you should get it from `/etc/sysconfig/language` after loading `rc.status`.  (This is assuming some variety of SuSE, which seems safe given `rc.status`; if it's a BSD, I don't know where it's currently stored.)  The variables will be the usual ones with `RC_` prepended (e.g. `RC_LC_ALL`).